# OAUTH for Twitter

Tags: java, exception, twitter, oauth, scribe

I am coding `OAUTH` for Twitter using `Scribe` framework.

I know that it use `Client ID` and `Client secret` for OAUTH. After OAUTH I will get user information.

I am getting this exception
 `org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Problems while creating connection.`

Do I need any certificate? What other things I need to make this OAUTH working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certificate is needed and it should be added in `servers truststore.`